# Get the the closest higher number from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file. inside there is text like that (no header):

```
1,2,5,7
```

I'm trying to get the the closest number to 3, but higher than 3. the answer would be 5.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    num = float("10")
    print(min(filter(lambda x: x > num, lines)))
```

It doesn't work, it seems there a problem with the list or strings or array.
When I do it like this it works:

```
num = 3
li = [1,2,5,7]
print (min(filter(lambda x: x > num,li)))
```

I tried to write it like this [1,2,5,7] in myfile.txt, it's not working. f.read() and f.readlines() also not working.

Comment: What is the point of `num = float("10")`? Why not `num = 10` or `num = 10.0`?

Comment: Try printing `lines` and you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. First you only have one string `"1,2,5,7"` first. You need to get the individual values using `"1,2,5,7".split(",")`. And you need to of course parse the string to `float` or `int` in order to be able to do correct comparisons.

Another problem is that `min()` will throw an error for an empty sequence which you will have if `num` is bigger than any of the values in your text file (which is the case in your example). You can use the `default` keyword argument to supply a default value for this case.

In my implementation, as I wanted to print something to the screen I've provided a string but you could provide any value that makes sense for your use case.

```py
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    numbers = lines.split(",")
    num = float("10")
    print(min([float(x) for x in numbers if float(x) > num], default=f"No values bigger than {num}"))
```

Expected output:

```
No values bigger than 10.0
```

Comment: What if there is no higher number than num? i got an error IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 how to choose the highest in the list if num is bigger than the number in the list

Comment: I don't understand the question. When `num = 10`, it is bigger than all other values in the file and in that case my solution will print `No values bigger than 10.0`. So the return value of `min()` will either be a single number or a string. Which numbers did you use as input and which value for `num` to get that error?

Comment: Your code works well. thank you. Instead of No values smaller than  10. I want it to print the biggest number in the list. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Oh yes I see, I did an small mistake of print `smaller` instead of `bigger`. Sorry for that. Fixed it. But the result was/ is fine. My solution will print one of two things. The closest number to `num` which is bigger than `num` or in case there is no number bigger than `num` it will print `No values bigger than {value of num}`. Change `num` to `3` and you will see it prints what you want

Comment: How to print the biggest value from the list if there is no values bigger than "10". I want it to print 7

Comment: In that case adjust the default value to be the maximum value. You can do that using `max()` but then you need to make sure the list is not empty or return a default value for that case again.

Comment: I did it like this    print(min([float(x) for x in numbers if float(x) > num], default=max(numbers))) Thank you

Comment: Thats the right idea but `numbers` only contains `str` so you need to cast the values to `float` first and you need to check if `numbers` is empty otherwise an error will occur.

Answer (score -1):

This task screams for numpy

```
import numpy as np

fin = 'myfile.txt'
num = 2
a = np.loadtxt(fin, delimiter=',')
b = np.sort(a)
c = b[b > num][0]
print(c)
```

Comment: "this task screams for numpy" -- not really... numpy is pretty heavy for such a simple task

Comment: You could also simply return `np.min(a[a > num])`.

Comment: but loadtxt gets you through all possible formatting. And your latter np.min also uses numpy. Plus, the questions in stackoverflows are (rightly) requested to be minimal, but the solution might consider to be general enough for heavier data

Comment: The `np.min(a[a > num])` was a suggestion for how to improve your answer. There's nothing wrong with using numpy, I was just commenting that this task, which looks like homework to me, doesn't really "scream" numpy. OP clearly has some misconceptions about very fundamental Python, and suggesting a large, complex library like numpy is likely not in OP's best interest.

Comment: what if there is no higher number? i got an error IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
how to choose the highest in the list if there is no other choice